# How to fix: Sorry, the program "node" closed unexpectedly

Tags: dual-boot, crash

[Sorry, the program "node" closed unexpectedly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZYIc.png)

I get this error in every boot how to fix it?

16gb ram i7

Comment: How much RAM does your computer have? If you're unsure, open a terminal, run `free -h` and let us know what it shows. (Reply to this comment or edit your question.)